# Howto use cmake with boost asio?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-asio

I cannot get `boost::asio` to work with cmake in my c++ program. I have actually tried and googled for many hours, but I cannot get it to work!

I want to include `boost::asio` in my c++ Project under Ubuntu 18.04 with a cmake file.

So I installed the newest CMake (`cmake version 3.19.4`), and I downloaded boost version 1.74 and executed

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/
sudo ./b2 install
```

The install directory is `/home/boost/boost_1_74_0`. My CMake file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1.0)
# Project name
project (machine_tryout VERSION 1.0)

# Boost (header only)
#set(Boost_DEBUG 1)
set(BOOST_ROOT "$ENV{HOME}/boost/boost_1_74_0")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR  "$ENV{HOME}/boost/boost_1_74_0")
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/boost/boost_1_74_0/libs")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED Components asio) 
    
# Set Executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} source/tryout.cpp)
```

But everything I get is the following:

```
vm-umic@vm:~/Projects/tryout/build$ cmake ..
CMake Warning at /snap/cmake/775/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2034 (message):
  No header defined for asio; skipping header check (note: header-only
  libraries have no designated component)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


CMake Error at /snap/cmake/775/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: asio) (found version "1.74.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/cmake/775/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:582 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /snap/cmake/775/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2193 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/vm-umic/Projects/tryout/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

What in the world am I doing wrong? Isnt CMake telling me that it found Boost 1.74? CMake does *NOT* throw any errors if I try `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)`, but then linking does also not work. I explicitly tell CMake where to find the libraries, so why can't CMake finde Boost?

Comment: What is the full path to asio.hpp?

Comment: If the linking does not work then the linker error message would be helpful for everybody to assist you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using boost.asio in cMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078898/using-boost-asio-in-cmake)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1.0)
# Project name
project (machine_tryout VERSION 1.0)

# Boost (header only)
#set(Boost_DEBUG 1)
set(BOOST_ROOT "$ENV{HOME}/boost/boost_1_74_0")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR  "$ENV{HOME}/boost/boost_1_74_0")
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/boost/boost_1_74_0/libs")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED Components system) 
    
# Set Executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} source/tryout.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren’t nice. Please explain *why* this fixes the problem.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately this does not work as intended, it tells me:
`CMake Error at /snap/cmake/775/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Components system) (found version "1.74.0")`

Perhaps I did not correctly install boost? How can it find boost but not this library?

Comment: To answer @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica 's comment, it should work because although `boost asio` is header only, it depends on `boost system` for error handling so it links to the `boost system` binary. @U_flow it sounds like you haven't built `boost`. You can build it by following the instructions here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html or even easier by just installing it, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu. Note, Ubuntu is likely to install an older version than 1.74 or 1.75 (the latest).

Comment: The case of `find_package` keyword `COMPONENTS` matters here. The error message lists `Components` as missing library.

Comment: Btw, you are missing a call to `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

Comment: @kenba perhaps you are right and I havent't (successfully) built boost! I just reread the documentation on building and the "lib" folder should be built (although I have a "libs" (with an s) folder).
I have not used apt-get install, because it threw me a bunch of "uninstalled dependencies errors" so I thought it would be easier to install directly from source, but I guess some of the dependencies are needed...

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem, and found that I had missed a small but important step in the Boost installation: adding the installation directory (i.e. the `PREFIX` used in `b2 install --prefix=PREFIX`) to the `PATH` environment variable.

For me, this solved it – hopefully will for you too!