# Error with Cmake and boost Could NOT find Boost (missing: program_options)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I know this issue seems to pop and on a regular basis, however I haven't found a thread yet that solved my issue. If this is a duplicate question, I'd appreciate if you could link me to the correct thread :)

Intro: I'm trying to install https://github.com/mhekkel/mrc but **cmake** isn't happy with my **boost** version.

**cmake** version: 3.22.1

**Boost** version: 1.78.0

As c++ compiler I'm using **mingw** (might be relevant according to some threads here), so I've installed the boost libraries following this post: https://gist.github.com/sim642/29caef3cc8afaa273ce6#project-setup

I have then compiled the *program_options* package as described by boost (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) with

```
bootstrap
.\b2 package_options
```

Initially I'm getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR program_options) (Required
  is at least version "1.70.0")
```

So I changed the **CMakeList.txt** and added: `set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 1.78.0 1.78)`

Now **cmake** finds boost but not the required library *program_options*:

```
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1369 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1492 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2102 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:71 (find_package)`
```

I have then played around with setting the library direction: `set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR <DIR>)` but to no success.

With `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` I can see **cmake** is searching in the correct directories, so I feel like I'm missing something else?

DEBUG output:

```
C:\mrc\build>cmake ..
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1673 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.78.0;1.78;1.77.0;1.77;1.76.0;1.76;1.75.0;1.75;1.74.0;1.74;1.73.0;1.73;1.72.0;1.72;1.71.0;1.71;1.70.0;1.70"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1674 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1675 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1676 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1677 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = "1.78.0;1.78"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1678 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1710 ] BOOST_ROOT = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1711 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1712 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1713 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1714 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = "C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/bin.v2/libs"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1715 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1803 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1843 ] Boost_VERSION = "107800"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1844 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.78.0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1845 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107800"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1846 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1847 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "78"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1848 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1849 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1873 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1874 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-vc143;-vc142;-vc141;-vc140" (guessed)
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1910 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1988 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "-x64" (detected)
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1992 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1993 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-gd"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2053 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/bin.v2/libs;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2054 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/bin.v2/libs;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/Boost/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1369 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1492 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2102 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:71 (find_package)


-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-vc143-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc143-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc143-mt;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc142-mt;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc141-mt;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc140-mt;boost_program_options-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-mt-x64;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc143-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: program_options) (found suitable version
  "1.78.0", minimum required is "1.70.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:71 (find_package)
```

Comment: cmake seems to think you're using visual studio `_boost_COMPILER = "-vc143;-vc142;-vc141;-vc140" (guessed)` so is probably looking for visual studio boost libraries

Comment: Make sure all parts (CMake, bootstrap, b2, ...) see and use *the same toolchain*. This can be quite tricky on Windows...

Comment: Solution that worked for me: Packaged boost version - https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.78.0/

Comment: @AlanBirtles redid building the boost library "program_options" with gcc but to no effect. Should have noticed the comment on the boost website "Other command shells, such as MinGW's MSYS, are not supported—they may or may not work"

Comment: I don't think you needed to rebuild boost, just needed to make sure that cmake is configured to use gcc (or just use MSVC, it'll cause you far fewer problems than using MINGW)

Comment: Solutions go in the answer space below, not in the question. Do not add SOLVED to your question

Comment: See this post and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000702/howto-use-cmake-with-boost-asio/73748656, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It actually tells you: `set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR <DIR>)`

Translation: Open Boost folder and point to directory called Library.

Also this bit: `(Required is at least version "1.70.0")`

You appear to be using 1.78!

Boost should also be set in your environment variables:

- (Name) BOOST_ROOT
- (Value) C:\local\boost_1_70_0

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was quite trivial: I just had to set `Boost_LIB_PREFIX` to its appropriate value (`lib`).

In fact, by setting `set(Boost_DEBUG 1)`, I realized that `Boost_LIB_PREFIX` was assumed to be empty, thus CMake was looking for libraries with names like
*"boost_program_options-...."*
while it should be looking for
*"**lib**boost_program_options-...."*

Since Boost 1.83.0 built through `b2` on Windows creates *static* libraries with *'lib'* as prefix I just set `Boost_LIB_PREFIX` as *"lib"* in my CMake cache and everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing the output of your set (Boost-DEBUG ON), I noticed that cmake is searching for the MSVC version of Boost in the 'Searching for Program_ Options_ LIBRARY_ RELEASE: boost_ Program_ Options-vc143-mt-x64-1_78' line. However, in your article, you mentioned the use of the mgw compiler. To resolve this, cmake should search for library files similar to 'libboost_ Program_ Options-mgw17-mt-x64-1_78'. Therefore, you need to reinstall the Boost library that is suitable for the MGW version. The complete steps for this process are as follows:

1. Run 'bootstrap.bat gcc'
2. Execute 'b2.exe link=static,shared variant=debug,release toolset=gcc cxxflags="-std=c++20" address-model=64 install --prefix="Your installation path"'

In the above steps:

- The 'link' parameter specifies the linking method for the Boost library. Examples include 'static' and 'dynamic'.
- The 'toolset' parameter is used to specify the compilation toolset as gcc. You can also specify other toolsets like Clang or MSVC.
- 'address-model=64' indicates that the target platform is 64-bit. You can alternatively set it to 32 for a 32-bit platform.
- The 'variant' parameter specifies the build versions, including release and debug.
- The '--prefix' option allows you to specify the installation path.

Lastly, don't forget to add the following line to your environment variable BOOST_ROOT: 'BOOST_ROOT="Your installation path"'. This ensures that Boost is properly recognized.